# ios opencv filepath of cascade file

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, cascade

I am new to ios. Currently I am working on an app that uses opencv facetracker. 
Therefore I use C++ within Objective-C. My problem is, that the contructor of the C++ class, which handles the facetracking part, needs the file location of the cascade file. The Constructor looks like this:

```
VideoFaceDetector(const std::string cascadeFilePath);
```

Unfortunately the following code does not work(filepath changed for anonymity reasons):

```
const cv::String    CASCADE_FILE("/../../../../haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
```

Although the haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml file is within the Xcode project, it can not be loaded.
Is there a way to get the filepath of the cascade file within the C++ code? I have tried the approach from User: r4ghu

```
NSString *faceCascadePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             pathForResource:@"<your_cascade_name>"
                             ofType:@"xml"];
const CFIndex CASCADE_NAME_LEN = 2048;
char *CASCADE_NAME = (char *) malloc(CASCADE_NAME_LEN);
CFStringGetFileSystemRepresentation( (CFStringRef)faceCascadePath,
                                    CASCADE_NAME,
                                    CASCADE_NAME_LEN);
if(!face_cascade.load(CASCADE_NAME)) {
    cout << "Unable to load the face detector!!!!" << endl;
    exit(-1);
}
```

It did not work for me. 
Is there any other way?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. User r4ghu was right. But it was not clear for me, where to put that lines of code. If you want to load your cascade file correctly you would have to do that before you initialize your camera. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString * const TFCascadeFilename = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2";//Strings of haar file names

    NSString *TF_cascade_name = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:TFCascadeFilename ofType:@"xml"];

    bool check = false;
    //Load haar file, return error message if fail
    if (!(check = faceCascade.load( [TF_cascade_name UTF8String] ))) {
        NSLog(@"[Cascade File]: Could not load TF cascade!");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"[Cascade File]: Successfully loaded!");
    }
    NSLog(@"[path]: %@\n", TF_cascade_name);


    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView];
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30;
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
    self.videoCamera.rotateVideo = YES;
    [self.videoCamera start];
}
```

This worked for me.

nice greets.